# "SOA Serial Number Format is Invalid" warning by mxtoolbox.com - why?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, soa-record

When testing the SOA setting for example-domain.org on http://mxtoolbox.com/, it says that

```
SOA Serial Number Format is Invalid
```

The entry is

```
ns-885.awsdns-46.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

That, however, is exactly what Amazon suggest in their Route 53 documentation on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html

**mxtoolbox issues a warning - why?** They also consider the missing DMARC settings as an error.

Please bear with me - I am not a sysadmin. Any hint that uses a language that a developer can understand is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a recommendation that the SOA serial number use a format that is four digits of year, two digits of month, two digits of day and two digits of count of changes in the same day. This format is common, but far from universal (look at `.COM` for a high-profile example of a zone that doesn't). The tool you got the error message from is oversensitive and should be adjusted.

Comment: Yeah, so long as the number is incrementing the specific syntax doesn't matter. mxtoolbox is being a nuisance here.

Comment: It's important to note that what actually constitutes a greater/lower value is not immediately intuitive for large differences because of the special rules to allow for the controlled wrap around. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1982 for all the details.

Answer (score 12):

The `SOA` `SERIAL` field is specified to be an an unsigned integer value that has special rules for how it wraps around, and consequently also for how serial numbers are compared, etc.

[RFC1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.3.13) defines this field as:

> **SERIAL**
>
> The unsigned 32 bit version number of the original copy of
> the zone.  Zone transfers preserve this value.  This value
> wraps and should be compared using sequence space
> arithmetic.

The arithmetic of serial numbers is explained in detail in [RFC1982](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1982).

Anyway, the popular `YYYYMMDDnn` "format" is just a convention for picking integer values such that, when written out in decimal, convey some meaningful information to humans (may be helpful when troubleshooting). The use of such values have no special meaning in the system itself and using values that do not follow this convention is not an error.

Answer (score 4):

mxtoolbox issues a warning when your serial does not match XXXXMMDDnn *in their time zone*. Assuming you are east of their time zone, your serial **might be considered to be a day in the future** and not meet their suggested format, thus yielding to a warning.

Try again in some hours without touching the serial and the warning will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone confused as to which part of the record we are talking about, it is the "1".
So this...

```
ns-885.awsdns-46.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

could be changed to this (for 1st change of today, say)...

```
ns-885.awsdns-46.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 2022080201 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

That is, YYYYMMDDnn equals the combination of year, month, day, and number of changes made so far today starting from 01. Hope that helps clarify for non-technical people. :-)